# How do I check the status of my drivers and install them if needed?

Tags: drivers, 18.04

I'm trying to learn how to use Ubuntu, but I must say I didn't have half as many issues with 16 as I have had with 18.04

I'm using a laptop and I'm at a beginner-level. (But I'm willing to learn)
And basically I'm having a lot of lag, and perhaps I don't have the correct drivers.

I'd need an easy command to pull up my system info, and then run a check on my drivers and download what's needed.

Proc: AMD e1-1200 APU with Radeon HD graphics x2,
Mem: 3.5m total, 1.7g used, 651m free,
Swap: 3.6g total, 29m used, 3.6g free

CPU MHz:             778.147,
CPU max MHz:         1400.0000,
CPU min MHz:         777.0000

Comment: You're thinking of apps that run in the Windows environment. I'm not aware of anything similar in the Ubuntu/Linux environment. Maybe, describe more about your "lag" and we might come up with some ideas on how to cure that. Does the lag happen all of the time? Only in one app? When you're running a VPN? Etc.

Comment: I'll have to read more about the kernal system and the major differences between Linux and Windows, to better understand. But basically, my system is very slow upon installing ubuntu 18.04. Namely, application windows slowly opening, webpages and while trying to play Minecraft. Generally the entire system seems slow.

Comment: What processor? What speed? How much RAM/swap? What video subsystem/drivers? Edit your question to show me `free -h`.

Comment: I got the requested info added to my question. What would be your assessment?

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered before but in two parts.

First displaying loaded kernel modules.

> Linux (and Ubuntu as well) doesn't have separate entity as "device
>   drivers", Linux has kernel modules which could be called "drivers" for
>   real or virtual hardware depending on their functionality.
>
> Use `lsmod` or `cat /proc/modules` to see list of loaded kernel
>   modules. Also you can see list of all available (installed) kernel
>   modules in system using:
>
> ```
> ls -R /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/
> ```
>
> [Source | find list of installed device drivers ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EOKL.png)

Next, using Software Sources > Additional Drivers, for installing device drivers, often proprietary.

> ### Unity (15.10 and 15.04/14.04/13.04/14.10/13.10/12.10)
>
> Click on the gear icon on the top right corner of your screen and
>   click on "System Settings" from that menu, click on Software Sources
>   (or you can click on the Ubuntu button and search for "Sources":
>
> [image]
>
> and then on the Additional drivers tab:
>
> [image]
>
> [Source | How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)

Comment: I was running Ubuntu and I could not access my system settings at all. I then noticed you were running Unity and I switched to that and accessed my system settings/additional drivers tab. I've used the mentioned commands to pull up my driver info. And I'm running a Radeon HD 7310 graphics card. I was unable to verify if the driver is working correctly, and under the Additional Drivers tab, It searched and displayed "No additional drivers available.". next, I tried to find the driver on AMD's website. I was unable to find a linux Radeon HD 7310 driver.

Comment: [A6-7310 with Radeon R4](https://www.amd.com/en/support/apu/amd-series-processors/amd-a6-series-apu-for-laptops/a6-7310-radeon-r4-graphics) has Ubuntu and Linux drivers.  Officially Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 are supported, but I cannot foresee this being an issue. Review the install notes, as you will need to disable X display manager to install the Catalyst graphics driver.

Answer (score 1):

In 20.04,  go to the application launcher and launch "Additional Drivers"
here you can find available drivers for your hardware as well as see the ones you are using
Whereas in 18.04, you need to go to Software And Updates to : additional drivers and select the fifth option which is : Additional Drivers

Answer (score 0):

You may just not have enough horsepower to make Ubuntu speedy. Or you may have not installed the Radeon-specific video drivers. One solution is to use a version of Ubuntu that takes less resources, like Xubuntu. However, lets try these two things first...

**Attempt #1:**

Disable wayland, if it's running...

In `terminal`...

`sudo pico /etc/gdm3/custom.conf` # edit this file

change:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to:

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

then reboot.

**Attempt #2:**

Use the lightdm display manager...

In `terminal`...

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` # select lightdm and click OK

use

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` *(ignore any error messages about gdm3 not running)*

if you wish to set it back to gdm3 display manager.

then reboot.

**Attempt #3:**

Download the xubuntu .iso and burn it to a DVD or flash USB key. Boot to it, and see if things operate better for you. If they do, you may wish to switch from Ubuntu to Xubuntu.